I want to consume the same messages again when I restart my application using Apache Kafka but it takes almost 1 minute
I have a console application (the consumer). I want to consume the same messages again when I rerun my application. I have set: EnableAutoCommit = false but each time when I rerun my application it takes almost 1 minute to consume messages, why so long?

using Confluent.Kafka;

var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "...",
    SaslUsername = "....",
    SaslPassword = "....",
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    GroupId = "kafka-dotnet-getting-started",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
    EnableAutoCommit = false
};

const string topic = "purchases";

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) => {
    e.Cancel = true; 
    cts.Cancel();
};

Console.WriteLine($"Application start time: {DateTime.Now}");

using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
{
    consumer.Subscribe(topic);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var cr = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed at {DateTime.Now} event from topic {topic}: key = {cr.Message.Key,-10} value = {cr.Message.Value}");
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Ctrl-C was pressed.
    }
    finally
    {
        consumer.Close();
    }
}


Do you make sure that consumer.Close() is called before restart?

OK, you are right!!! I simply closed the application instead of use "ctrl-c" to cancel subscription and call consumer.Close() :D Thank you!

Make sure your properly using consumer.close().It is used to close network connection and trigger re-balance immediately which helps application to receive messages immediately after restarts.

Consider disposing your consumer by implementing IDisposable.
THis is what I do

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
